# Laravel 5.2 DB Query

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use `DB` to build a query like so:

Get all `Distributors` belonging to the `User` with their `Accounts` that have `Notes`.

I cant wrap my head around that query. Here is what I had that works in that it gets spits out the info I need in one array but 2 issues: the `note` `name` overwrites the `account` `name` since they are both called that, and I cant pass in a `$user->` to replace the `2`

Working (kind of)

```
        $user = Auth::user();

        $accounts   = DB::table('distributors')
                        ->join('accounts', function ($join) {
                                    $join->on('distributors.vip_abbv', '=', 'accounts.dist_abbv')
                                         ->where('distributors.user_id', '=', 2);
                                })
                        ->join('notes', 'notes.account_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
                        ->select('accounts.name', 'notes.*')
                        ->get();
```

What I need

$user = Auth::user();

```
    $accounts   = DB::table('distributors')
                    ->join('accounts', function ($join, $user) {
                                $join->on('distributors.vip_abbv', '=', 'accounts.dist_abbv')
                                     ->where('distributors.user_id', '=', $user->id);
                            })
                    ->join('notes', 'notes.account_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
                    ->select('accounts.name (this is overwritten. can I change it to come out account_name so it doesnt?)', 'notes.*')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: any errors @Packy

Comment: The error was passing a second parameter with $join so I just used Auth for current user ID opposed to a variable and it worked. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for account name:

```
  ->select('accounts.name as custom_account_name')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect!! That worked for the account name. Just need to pass in the user->id

Comment: I actually got the id in there by just using `Auth::user()->id` opposed to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
DB::table('distributors')
    ->join('accounts', function ($join) use ($user) {
          $join->on('distributors.vip_abbv', '=', 'accounts.dist_abbv')
               ->where('distributors.user_id', '=', $user->id);
          })
    ->join('notes', 'notes.account_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
    ->select('accounts.name as account_name', 'notes.*')
    ->get();
```